# How do I remove space when using \nocite?

Tags: spacing, citing

When I use the \nocite command, it produces a space that looks bad. So this:

```
Synthetic biology witnessed a surge of development over the past two 
decades~\nocite{andrianantoandro_SyntheticBiologyNew_2006,
lukas_DesigningEncodingModels_2009}.
```

Renders to this:

> Synthetic biology witnessed a surge of development over the past two
> decades .

How do I avoid that whitespace before the full stop?

Comment: The space comes before the `\nocite` command, so just remove it. It's not really anything to do with `\nocite` itself. `\nocite` isn't really designed to be used within text really.

Comment: In most implementations `\nocite` uses the 'standard LaTeX trick' `\@bsphack` and `\@esphack` to avoid messing with space. So usually it should be fine used in text, but if you put a `~` in front of the command that (a non-breakable space) is what you get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`~` is the command for a non-breaking space.  It's useful for `~\cite{mylabel}` so that the `[1]` doesn't end up on the next line by itself.  But if you don't want the space, then you don't need the `~`, and should just have

```
... over the past two decades\nocite{andrianantoandro_SyntheticBiologyNew_2006,lukas_DesigningEncodingModels_2009}.
```